# DACircularProgressView in UITableViewCell only visible when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using `DACircularProgressView` in my app and I'm trying to put it into a `UITableViewCell`.

However, the progress view is invisible unless the cell is selected.

[image]

There is only a very small amount of code in setting it up...

Custom cell subclass...

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.141 green:0.705 blue:0.553 alpha:1.0];
    self.progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.progressView.thicknessRatio = 0.1;
}
```

TableViewController...

```
- (void)configureCell:(CCQuickViewMatchTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Match *match = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.progressView.progress = (float)arc4random_uniform(90) / 90.0;
    cell.homeTeamNameLabel.text = match.homeTeam.name;
    cell.awayTeamNameLabel.text = match.awayTeam.name;
    cell.homeTeamScoreLabel.text = match.homeTeamScore;
    cell.awayTeamScoreLabel.text = match.awayTeamScore;
}
```

I think I need to override some function of the UITableViewCell but I'm not sure which or why?

Comment: Try `[cell.progressView setProgress:(float)arc4random_uniform(90)/90 animated:YES]`, it seems to send `setNeedsDisplay` call to the layer when `animated=YES`.

Comment: @Amar Thanks, I tried that (thought it might do it) but it's still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it but not sure how exactly.

I was looking at the `DACircularProgressView` code and noticed it had `UIAppearance` compatible properties.

I removed my `- (void)awakeFromNib` code and set the appearance in the `AppDelegate`.

This now works perfectly :D

[image]